# Class private method in newest chrome

Tags: javascript, class, oop, private

I have newest google chrome currently version 80.0.3987.87. I copied [example from JS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_Methods) which is

```js
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 'hello world'
  }

  getPrivateMessage() {
      return #privateMethod()
  }
}

const instance = new ClassWithPrivateMethod()
console.log(instance.getPrivateMessage())
// expected output: "hello worl​d"
```

and paste it to console. I should get Hello World but instead I have error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('

from second line where I declare private method. Why error, what is wrong with my environment? I don't think MDN docs are incorrect..

Comment: "*I don't think MDN docs are incorrect.*" - at least they are incomplete. There is no compatibility table for private class *methods* (which are separate from ordinary fields), and apparently they are not supported by your Chrome version.

Comment: can # allowed as start of method name https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: It is now supported by chrome.
the same example will work on chrome devtools if you add `this` to getPrivateMessage method:
 `getPrivateMessage() {   return this.#privateMethod(); }`

As far as I can tell the proposal is still just stage 3
you can check here [Development history & status](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#status)
for more details about the process
MDN only says that chrome supports private class **fields**
not **methods**.
That's the reason you get an error.
However, as mentioned `private fields` are supported by                                                                                 chrome and you can use
something similar to that :

```js
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod

  constructor(){
      this.#privateMethod = function(){
          return 'hello world';
      };
  }

  getPrivateMessage() {
      return this.#privateMethod();
  }
}
const instance = new ClassWithPrivateMethod();
console.log(instance.getPrivateMessage());
```

Comment: Can you provide some description? What do you mean?

Comment: Yes gimme a sec

Comment: hope it helped you, if not feel free to ask more questions

Comment: well it said full support in node.js v12, which not after i test

Answer (score 0):

### Try the following

- Use arrow function
- Where you are calling your method, use the `this.#methodName()`
- Therefore, you've to correct this line of code `return #privateMethod()` to `return this.#privateMethod()`
- This should also work with nodejs v12.0.00 above

```js
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod = () => {
    // use arrow function
    return 'hello world'
  }

  getPrivateMessage() {
      return this.#privateMethod()
  }
}

const instance = new ClassWithPrivateMethod()
console.log(instance.getPrivateMessage())
// expected output: "hello worl​d"
```